# plotly 3D surface plot with curvature

Tags: ggplot2, graphics, 3d, plotly

For example, I like to demonstrate the 3d surface `z = sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))/sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` and the curvature `x*y = 10`.

I could do the surface with the following code, but I do know how to add the curvature.

```
# Load the required packages
library(plotly)

# Generate data for the x, y, and z coordinates
x <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 50)
y <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 50)
z <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) {sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))/sqrt(x^2 + y^2)})

# Create a 3D surface plot
surface <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z, type = "surface")
```

It doesn't have to be `plotly`, any other suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning curvature, does that mean you want to display another matrix of results corresponding to x*y?

If so, does the following code answer your question?

```
### Import libraries
library(plotly)

### Pre-processing
# Generate data for the x, y, and z coordinates
x <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 50)
y <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 50)
z <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) {sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))/sqrt(x^2 + y^2)})

# Generate a second matrix of results
z2 <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) {(x*y)})

### Display plot
# Create a 3D surface plot
surface <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z, type = "surface")

# Add another layer
surface %>% add_surface(z = ~z2, opacity = 0.98)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. However, I need `10 = x*y`. The trick part is this curvature is perpendicular to the bottom.

Comment: When you build `z2` in my example, you should solve `x * y = 10` and then you plot it. I am not sure what you want to do. Do you have an example, a link to see what you want the plot to look like?